# python: NameError Name input

Tags: python

I was trying to get some input in python and I have no idea what is my problem

```
 name = input("What's your name?")
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
year = str((100 - age) + 2018)
print("Hello "+ name + ",in " + year + "you'll be 100 y.o")
```

and when I use my name as input like "shayan", thats came out:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'shayan' is not defined
```

I tri my code in "atom" , "sublime" , "visual studio code"

Comment: Please post the full code. The part of code in the above question isn't indicating the line where the error was encountered.

Comment: Atom, Sublime and VS Code are text editors. They make no difference to how the program runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're on python 2, so `input` in python is basically `eval(input(...))` in python 3, so it will take inputs as code, not strings, so gotta use `raw_input` in python 2:

```
name = raw_input("What's your name?")
age = input("How old are you?")
year = str((100 - age) + 2018)
print("Hello "+ name + ",in " + year + "you'll be 100 y.o")
```